# Convert Mercurial to Git repository on Windows and without Python

Tags: windows, git, version-control, mercurial, smartgit

For some reasons I prefer to avoid using Python.

But all I found is either Python scripts or unix specific instructions or something that doesn't have downloadable executables or unclear how to install it in windows.

Can you suggest any tool or service?

Comment: If you use Mercurial, you have Python in your system.

Comment: @jedema, already realized that...

Comment: Just by curiosity, why to avoid python using ?

Comment: @jedema the hell with different runtime versions (and each installation either overwrites Python path in environment variables or sometimes requires them to be created/changed manually). some applications work with old Python version but new version installation breaks everything. I can't use both GitStack and Blender because they require different Python versions in environment variables! Too much headache!

Comment: I understand. This is a real problem. I hope Python 2 will disappear bit by bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a plugin [here](http://hg-git.github.io/) for that.

Comment: How to install it for smartgit?

Comment: The instructions says that it requires to install Dulwich which is a again Python library.

Comment: I miss understood.  I thought you wanted no additional Python installation, assuming you already had Mercurial installed.  So you are saying you do not have Mercurial installed?

Comment: Yes, the mercurial is installed as a part of SmartGit. Do you mean I don't need Dulwich?

Comment: Hmm, I'm not sure about that, just thought that SmartGit already have mercurial as it operates my repository... but I can install mercurial, it's not a problem.

Comment: OK, I did a little digging, Dulwich (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dulwich) is a Python library for interacting with Git, so yes it is needed.  Are you OK with installing this library?  The Mercurial installation with SmartGit should be sufficient.

Comment: Yes, I can install it if it doesn't require a seperate Python installation.

Comment: SmartGit is Java, how do you use Pythonic lib with it?!

Comment: SmartGit interfaces with Mercurial which is Python.  The plugin is for Mercurial.  I assume you will need to drop to the shell to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe just install Win-build of CLI-Mercurial or standalone TortoiseHG (plus HG-Git)?

I haven't Python per se on my box, only THG (which have Dulwich) and HG-Git anf Git-repos are pushable